# How do you know if a OledbDataAdapter found a primary key?

Tags: .net, vb.net, ado, adodb

I'm hitting a stored procedure that can return multiple records and I insert them into a datatable using `dataadapter.fill(myTable, recordSet)`.

I know the first column in the returned recordset is the primary key, but I don't think my oledbadapter is picking it up which is causing data duplication. I'm setting `MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey`. The only column the stored procedure doesn't return is the index column.

Any ideas?

In case it matters, I'm using ADODB and (just switched over) mysqlserver. Why not use ADO.NET someone may ask or a mysqldataadapter? I'm new, voice doesn't count yet, and eventually we'll switch our code they tell me.

Comment: And no luck with [OleDbDataAdapter.FillSchema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.fillschema(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I decided to use a strong typed data table instead and assigned the primary key. I was trying to be generic as possible, but I gotta do what I gotta do.